# Multiline Label Box VBA

Tags: excel, vba, range, multiline, multilabel-classification

I have an issue with trying to make muliline entrys to a label box(inside a form), dont want to use a text box, I know there is a way to do it in code but I just can't seem to get it around my head all I try comes out false or returns only one value. Basicly what I am traying to do is import a comlumn of text entrys , from colum B till the first empty cell, the text is already in the column. Now I need to get that text into multiple lines of a label field when I click the button.

Any help will be greatly appriciated.

Thank you!

```
Private Sub readbtn_Click()
Dim content As Variant
content = 1
Range("B1").Select
Do While Range("B" & content) <> ""
Me.ValuesLbl.Caption = Range("B" & content)
content = content + 1
Loop

Selection.End(xlDown).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Add carriage returns (`vbcr`)?

Comment: ok but where I hvae tried with vbcr and vbcrlf

Comment: I've been looking and trying for 3 hours now maybe I just cant see it anymore :-)

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? Sample data and expected result may also be useful

Comment: " ValuesLbl.Caption = ValuesLbl.Caption & content & vbCrLf " and other variations but either I am not positioning the codeline where it should be or it not what I need, I've ran out of ideas